# Group certain columns and summing up another column from a CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have data in a csv that needs to be parsed. It looks like:

```
Date,Tag,Amount
13/06/2018,ABC,6750000
13/06/2018,ABC,159800
24/05/2018,ABC,-1848920
16/05/2018,AB,-1829700
16/05/2018,AB,3600000
28/06/2018,A,15938000
16/05/2018,AB,3748998
28/06/2018,A,1035000
28/06/2018,A,1035000
14/06/2018,ABC,2122717
```

You can see each date has a tag and number next to it. 
what i am trying to achieve is to make the date and tag the key and group by the date and tag and to sum up the amount.

expected result

```
Date,Tag,Amount
13/06/2018,ABC,5220680
16/05/2018,AB,5519298
28/06/2018,A,18008000
14/06/2018,ABC,2122717
```

the code i am using now is below which is not working.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

d = defaultdict(int)

with open("file.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        tokens = [t.strip() for t in line.split(",")]
        try:
            date = int(tokens[0])
            tag = int(tokens[1])
            amount = int(tokens[2])
        except ValueError:
            continue
        d[date] += amount

print d
```

could someone show me how to aheive this please without using pandas

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org). With the exception that you *have to* code this by yourself, you can just install the pandas module, import it (`import pandas as pd`) as solve this problem with 2 simple and intuitive lines of code

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
>>> df.groupby(['Date', 'Tag']).Amount.sum()

Date        Tag
13/06/2018  ABC     6909800
14/06/2018  ABC     2122717
16/05/2018  AB      5519298
24/05/2018  ABC    -1848920
28/06/2018  A      18008000
```

---

If you really *need* to code this yourself, you can use a nested `defaultdict` so you can have two layers of groupby. Also, why you try to cast to `int` the `date` and the `tag`? Makes no sense at all. Just remove it.

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

for line in z:
    tokens = [t.strip() for t in line.split(",")]
    try:
        date = tokens[0]
        tag = tokens[1]
        amount = int(tokens[2])
    except ValueError as e:
        continue
    d[date][tag] += amount
```

The output is:

```
13/06/2018 ABC 6909800
24/05/2018 ABC -1848920
16/05/2018 AB 5519298
28/06/2018 A 18008000
14/06/2018 ABC 2122717
```

To output the result above, just iterate through the items:

```
for k,v in d.items():
    for k2, v2 in v.items():
        print(k,k2,v2)
```

To make your code even better, read the *first line* only, and then iterate from the second line til the end. That way, your try/except can be removed and you'd get a simpler and cleaner code. But you can pick up from here, right? ;)

To write to a csv, simply

```
s = '\n'.join(['{0} {1} {2}'.format(k, k2, v2) for k,v in d.items() for k2,v2 in v.items()])
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(s)
```

Comment: i need to achieve this without using pandas

Comment: @R.Dave Ok.. in that case, you just have to change a simple detail. Will edit

Comment: thank you for your example, could you also help me with outputting the results into a csv than printing?

Comment: i think your example is not grouping the date with the tag and summing up the amount. i gave it ago and

Comment: @R.Dave yea it is, look at the output! It is the expected you posted :) added an example of writing to csv.

Comment: Hi RafaelC, just want to confirm that does you code sum up negative numbers? also how can i add the header in the output and how do i make the output to be csv?

Comment: also if i wanted to bring out other columns but i dont want to group by or sum them up..how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

result = defaultdict(int)
with open(filename) as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    header = next(reader)
    for line in reader:
        result[tuple(line[:2])] += int(line[2])

print(header)
for k, v in result.items():
    print(k[0], k[1], v)
```

**Output:**

```
14/06/2018 ABC 2122717
13/06/2018 ABC 6909800
28/06/2018 A 18008000
16/05/2018 AB 5519298
24/05/2018 ABC -1848920
```

---

**To CSV**

```
with open(filename, "wb") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(header)
    for k, v in result.items():
        writer.writerow([k[0], k[1], v])
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh, does you example above grouping the date and tag column and summing up the amount column ?

Comment: Yes...`tuple(line[:2])` is the date and tag. `line[2]` is the amount

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby 
import csv
header, *data = csv.reader(open('filename.csv'))
new_data = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda x:x[:2]), key=lambda x:x[:2])]
results = [[*a, sum(int(c) for *_, c in b)] for a, b in new_data]
with open('calc_results.csv', 'w') as f:
  write = csv.writer(f)
  write.writerows([header, *results])
```

Output:

```
Date,Tag,Amount
13/06/2018,ABC,6909800
14/06/2018,ABC,2122717
16/05/2018,AB,5519298
24/05/2018,ABC,-1848920
28/06/2018,A,18008000
```